# How do I create a comma separated list from mixin's arguments?

Tags: css, sass, dry, scss-mixins

To avoid boilerplate, I want to write a function/mixin taking a list of CSS properties (at least one) and write the same transition for each, and also output `will-change` accordingly. Given `margin-left, width`, to output:

```scss
{
  transition: margin-left $some-value, width $some-value;
  will-change: margin-left, width;
}
```

I found I can use an arguments list with a spread operator (`@mixin some-mixin($args...)`) and tried looping using `@each`, but I don't really know how to use `@each` inside a single property and concatenate the results with a comma, without having an end comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [the github comment](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/706#issuecomment-16137349) which led me to the answer.

---

There is a function called [append](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list/#append) in `'sass:list'`, which can be used to create a comma separated list, as follows:

```scss
@use "sass:list";

$timing: 0.42s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);

@mixin transition($args...) {
  $tr: ();
  $wc: ();
  @each $arg in $args {
    $tr: append($tr, append($arg, $timing, space), comma);
    $wc: append($wc, $arg, comma);
  }
  transition: $tr;
  will-change: $wc;
}
```

**Input** (SCSS):

```scss
.foo {
  @include transition(width, margin-left);
}
.bar {
  @include transition(transform);
}
```

**Output** (CSS):

```css
.foo {
  transition: width 0.42s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), margin-left 0.42s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  will-change: width, margin-left;
}

.bar {
  transition: transform 0.42s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}
```

See it working in [SASS: Playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#eJx1j8EOgyAMhu8+RQ8cMEEyzU7u4qsg4mwiYBDjsmXvvsri9LIEkp/m+0pbliwG5WaM6F0NF3mtZtBLi7pozRNN4FQScKEjKwFlfssaiw90cGicqXCfpZQ5vDIAFmvgxFFaC73nxig9wEYCyclI9JdX02Rcx1kUv0iEgNNwAuZJaZML0N5alZruX+wOPQR8zQN60z3vyOJWXXEcCz0odzd16nLL3pnsvU9TNej0uHTmvOWKXRwEWGqPrhhNH/PktCr8dVLsfbAb+gHaYG68).